# Should you preprocess data in SARIMAX or ARIMAX

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, feature-scaling

Is it wise to scale exog variables in an ARIMAX/SARIMAX?

We can assume that we have dummy variables and continuous variables (0-1000)